# dotted lines in addition to outlier in geom_box

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I add dotted lines and horizontal bars at the end of the dotted lines to my boxplot in ggplot?
By default it creates a vertical lines going out from the box.  Please see example below how I want it:

here is my code

```
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(Length,levels=18:26), logFC)) + 
         geom_boxplot(fill = "white") + 
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-5,5)) +
         theme_bw(base_size=45) + 
         scale_x_discrete("", breaks=factor(18:26), drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238278/fine-tuning-ggplot2s-geom-boxplot might help

Comment: Please add a minimal data set to make your code reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

@CMichael cites the answer.  This merely illustrates it.  First, some toy data.

```
year <- rep("2014", 10)
total <- c(seq(55, 90, 5), 100, 40)
df <- data.frame(year = as.factor(year), total = total)
```

Then the plot, showing dotted lines and color.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(year), y=total)) + 
  geom_boxplot(linetype = "dotted", color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]