# How to customize whisker lines on a geom_box plot differently than the lines of the box itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Because of a demanding end user, I need to learn whether the whisker lines on a `geom_box` plot can be colored or typed differently than the box itself?

Having just considered [boxplot with colored and dotted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232835/dotted-lines-in-addition-to-outlier-in-geom-box/29371949#29371949), I have created a minimal example.

```
year <- rep("2014", 10)
total <- c(seq(55, 90, 5), 100, 40)
df <- data.frame(year = as.factor(year), total = total)

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(year), y=total)) + 
  geom_boxplot(linetype = "dotted", color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
```

Can the plot below have green whiskers, keeping the red box, or solid whiskers keeping the dotted box?

[image]

This SO question tells us that base R permits whisker line customization aplenty.  [bxp has several parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889977/r-boxplot-how-to-customize-the-appearance-of-the-box-and-whisker-plots-e-g-r)

Comment: If this does answer your question, you should put submit it as an answer rather than editing it into your question.

Comment: @Gregor, thank you.  I hadn't ever used the method of self-answering.  Oddly, the comment of user20650 was removed.  I wanted to upflag the comment.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT after comment: I didn't spot the SO question user20650 graciously pointed out. Here is its answer -- plot boxplots twice.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(year), y=total)) + 
  geom_boxplot(linetype = "dotted", color = "red") +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=..lower.., ymax=..upper..)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: what do you mean by **lower** and **uper** in `aes` of the second boxplot ?

Comment: That was a long time ago!  I think the double periods tells the second boxplot to draw on the same data (df).